# Getting all firebase data through loop

Tags: android, database, loops, firebase-realtime-database, smsmanager

I have a firebase database where contacts are saved. I want to fetch all the numbers of contacts and send them message one by one. I read it could be done by a for loop but the loop only returns the last number inserted, not all the numbers. Here is the code below:

```
 dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            ArrayList<String> Userlist=new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot dsp : snapshot.getChildren())
               Userlist.add(String.valueof(dsp.getValue()));

           for(int i = 0; i<Userlist.size();i++)
{
show.setText(Userlist.get(i);
}
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Please tell me a method through which I can fetch all the numbers of contacts and send them message one by one.
The code for sending the message is given below:

```
String phoneNumber="1234567890";

        String message="I need help";
        SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,null,message,null,null);
```

My database structure is attached as well. Please have a look and guide me. I will be thankfuk to you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a firebase database where contacts are saved. I want to fetch
> all the numbers of contacts and send them message one by one. I read
> it could be done by a for loop but the loop only returns the last
> number inserted, not all the numbers.

The problem is you're trying to set `ArrayList` items to `TextView` with a loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i<Userlist.size();i++){
    show.setText(Userlist.get(i);
}
```

Setting text to `TextView` with loop changes `TextView`'s text with every step of the loop so the `TextView` will show only the last item of the list. If you only use `ArrayList` for putting `String` into it and setting for `TextView` (according to your code it's), using `ArrayList` is useless.
Inside `onDataChange()` method before getting your data, create an empty `String` and while you're getting your data expand your `String` with data. At the end of `for` loop `String` text will have all data and you can set it to `TextView`.

```
dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         String text = "";
         for (DataSnapshot dsp : snapshot.getChildren()){
             Map<String, Object> datas = (Map<String, Object>) dsp.getValue();
             text += datas.get("number").toString() + "\n";
         }
         tv.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

> Please tell me a method through which I can fetch all the numbers of
> contacts and send them message one by one.

You have 2 options for getting your values. You can use `Map` or you can create your `Java Object`.

**Using Map:**

```
private void sendMessage(DatabaseReference dbRef) {
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                SmsManager smsManager= SmsManager.getDefault();
                for (DataSnapshot dsp: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Map<String, Object> datas = (Map<String, Object>) dsp.getValue();
                    String phoneNumber = datas.get("number").toString();
                    String message="I need help";
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,null,message,null,null);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
}
```

**Using Java Object:**

If you want to use `Java Object` you need to create class which has a fields like database structure (fields has to same like contacts child).

Users.class (`Java Object`):

```
public class Users {

    private String name, number, email;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String name, String number, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Then you can get your data as an object.

```
private void sendMessage(DatabaseReference dbRef) {
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                SmsManager smsManager= SmsManager.getDefault();
                for (DataSnapshot dsp: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Users user = dsp.getValue(Users.class);
                    String phoneNumber = user.getNumber();
                    String message="I need help";
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,null,message,null,null);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
}
```

Both `sendMessage()` methods are getting data from database according to given `DatabaseReference` and using your code for sending message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(int i = 0; i<Userlist.size();i++)
     {
       show.append(userlist.get(i)+",");
        }
```

your all number display with this